# How do i do this ?page=content&page=profile

Tags: php

how can you do the example: ?page=content&page=profile
**Using Php** or **Something else**
Can you help me every one?
I just done all of my projects except this one
Pls

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pleas take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is "the example"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP function [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). However in your example, you have twice "page" query parameter: this is not good, you can't have many times the same parameter. So change it or put both values in one parameter.

```php
$params = ['page' => 'content', 'other_param' => 'profile'];
echo http_build_query($params);
```

Comment: Thanks i get it now Im am just a beginner of php language

Comment: What about using $_GET METHOD how do i do that

Comment: Don't worry, we all have been beginner :). `$_GET` contains the query parameters your request will receive. So `$_GET['page']` will have `'content'` as value and `$_GET['other_param']` will have 'profile' as value. THe $_GET type is array, so if you need to rebuild an URL with these, put $_GET in http_build_query function. Just be careful if $_GET contains other params you don't need.

Comment: Look my website ot

Comment: Heres my website: https://nobb.cf/other-files/description_test